# html <input needs to contain specific text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a input field and a button. Now I want it to only accept text that contains words I choose.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="fep-post-id" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>">

    <button type="button" id="fep-submit-post" class="active-btn">Go</button><img class="fep-loading-img" src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'static/img/ajax-loading.gif', dirname(__FILE__) ); ?>"/>
```

It is a submit form where people can only submit urls from specific websites. It is a php file within a Wordpress plugin

I tried the script solution but it is messing with the plugin scripts.js I think. I assume I need to add some code in the snippet:

```
$("#fep-submit-post.active-btn").on('click', function() {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        var title           = $("#fep-post-title").val();
        var content         = $("#fep-post-content").val();
        var bio             = $("#fep-about").val();
        var category        = $("#fep-category").val();
        var tags            = $("#fep-tags").val();
        var pid             = $("#fep-post-id").val();
        var fimg            = $("#fep-featured-image-id").val();
        var nonce           = $("#fepnonce").val();
        var message_box     = $('#fep-message');
        var form_container  = $('#fep-new-post');
        var submit_btn      = $('#fep-submit-post');
        var load_img        = $("img.fep-loading-img");
        var submission_form = $('#fep-submission-form');
        var post_id_input   = $("#fep-post-id");
        var errors          = post_has_errors(title, content, bio, category, tags, fimg);
        if( errors ){
            if( form_container.offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() ){
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: form_container.offset().top-10 }, 'slow'); }
            message_box.removeClass('success').addClass('warning').html('').show().append(errors);
            return;
        }
```

---

These are the 2 files I use:

scripts.js

http://pastebin.com/4SFUbhiP

form.php

Between ===>>>>> and <<<<====== is the input field I need validated.
Below is the submit button.
http://pastebin.com/G53HScu3

Comment: why don't you use the <select><option></option></select> tag?

Comment: I agree with @ParkBroom. Using a `<select>` tag with options set allows you to control the choices users make in a much simpler way. It would also allow you to avoid trying to catch typos in URLs if the choices are pre-populated.

Comment: That will create a drop down list? i don't need that. I have a input field/box where people can submit urls. The urls need to contain specific text. Maybe i was not clear enough ;-)

Comment: It does not need to be a drop down list but can be a scrollable list (perhaps of one row) use the `size` attribute for the select box.

Comment: To perhaps help other users since I think I follow `Maarten`'s goals a bit more, imagine having users link a video. They can insert a `youtube.com?v=` link, or a `dailymotion.com` link, but not a `facebook.com` link. If someone were simply choosing from 3 link options, a dropdown might make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! :-)
i have added this code to the scripts.js

> if ( title.toLowerCase().indexOf('collection') == -1 )
>           error_string += 'alleen....
> ';

if title/url not contains collection it shows error else it will submit the link. Thanks!

Comment: when i need to filter 2 domains i use this: `if ( title.toLowerCase().indexOf('collection') == -1 )
  if ( title.toLowerCase().indexOf('collection2') == -1 )
        error_string += 'alleen....<br/>';
;`

Answer (score 1):

I would do this

```
<form onsubmit="return validator()">

    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="fep-post-id" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>">

    <button type="button" id="fep-submit-post" class="active-btn">Go</button><img class="fep-loading-img" src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'static/img/ajax-loading.gif', dirname(__FILE__) ); ?>"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var validator = function(){
        switch (variable) {
            case "allowed":
                submit form;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
     }
</script>
```

Returning false inside the onsubmit attribute will stop the form from submitting. I just gave a basic example, using "allowed", but you would probably have to use string functions to determine if the base URL was one of your trusted websites.

There are probably better ways of doing this - maybe using selects - but with a little modification this should achieve your goal.

Comment: Great, will play with it.

Comment: It is not doing anything. It just send the stuff entered in the input field. I think it makes more sense if i show the 2 files i am using. Maybe i can edit or add some code within the scripts.js file to make it work. Will show the 2 files in my question on top of this page.